# How to use @Parameters together with ITestContext in TestNG?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I am currently writing a test in TestNG. Currently I have the following method:

```
@Parameters({"clickRememberMe"})
@Test
public void runTest(String clickRememberMe) {
}
```

Now I have found that a TestNG class called `org.testng.ITestContext` can be used to share data between tests, which I want to use. The tutorial showing it told me to do this:

```
@Test
public void runTest(ITestContext itc){
}
```

And this also works. However, now I want to use parameters **together with** the `ITestContext` like follows:

```
@Parameters({"clickRememberMe"})
@Test
public void runTest(ITestContext itc, String clickRememberMe) {
}
```

Sadly, this throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Is there any way to use @Parameters together with ITestContext in TestNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found the solution. Instead of:

```
@Parameters({"clickRememberMe"})
@Test
public void runTest(ITestContext itc, String clickRememberMe) {
}
```

I had to put the ITestContext after the parameters, like this:

```
@Parameters({"clickRememberMe"})
@Test
public void runTest(String clickRememberMe, ITestContext itc) {
}
```